# How to display random child pages of a parent page in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to display random child pages of a parent page, but I get random posts which I dont want to be included in the display area.

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( array ( 'orderby' => 'rand', 'posts_per_page' => '1', 'pagename=guide') );
```

So, what I want is to display random child pages of a parent page who slug is guide, but instead I get random posts which is quite different from what I want. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters   you'll want to use `post_parent=<page id>` instead of pagename=guide I think

Comment: That doesn't work too :(

Comment: It'd show the same result it was showing before

Comment: Is the problem that you're getting posts that are not children of your page?

Comment: yeah thats what the problem is. I am getting random posts

Comment: If it works for you please accept :) It is working on a fresh copy of WP 3.6.1 on my machine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is working for me. the `post_type` is the important part since otherwise it doesn't seem WP will query against the pages. The post_parent should be the integer id of your page.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'orderby' => 'rand', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'post_type' =>   'page', 'post_parent' => '2' )) ;
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul>';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
        echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$my_wp_query = new WP_Query(); // Setup query object
$all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page')); // Get all pages
$children = get_page_children( get_the_id(), $all_wp_pages); // Get the children pages from list of all pages
$rand = rand(0, (count( $children) - 1)); // Count children and get a random number from that range
print_r( $children[$rand]); // Print random child object
```

Hope this helps!